# how do i make my app open up with google maps by default android wild fire

Tags: helper

hi all i have made a app using appsgeyser.com the app is for railway access point that i have made on google maps now i have saved the url as a bookmark on my phone and when i open it all works well .but that is because it askes me when i open it do i want to use internet or maps so i choose maps ..so i have now added this url to appsgeyser and downloaded app to phone but when i open the app its not using google maps so when i click on a access it does not show direction or any info //
so basicle how do i make the url of my google maps open up by default on my phone 
[railway access points](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/ms?vps=2&hl=en&ie=UTF8&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=207922429402345654731.00049fa3636c77311a5c5)

Answer (score 0):

Leah from AppsGeyser here. Did you make sure to enable Geolocation on your app? 
To do it, you need to go to your AppsGeyser Dashboard, go to the Edit tab, choose the Advanced tab, and then choose the checkbox that says 'App can get location data.' You'll need to hit Create again, and download the app again to see the change. If that doesn't help, feel free to drop me an email Leah (at) AppsGeyser.com

Leah